# Android service не переподключается к серверу когда телефон заблокирован

Tags: java, android, сокет, service

Сервис запущен методом

```
Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, Connection_service.class);
startService(intent);
```

В самом сервисе идет подключение к серверу

```
SocketAddress adr = new InetSocketAddress(java.net.InetAddress.getByName(...
s.connect(adr, connectTime);
        s.setSoTimeout(readTime);
        s.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        s.setKeepAlive(true);
        inMes = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        outMes = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
```

В случае разрыва соединения переподключается тем же способом.

Вопрос в том, что если выключить надолго на телефоне экран(минут 10) то соединение пропадает и при переподключении не устанавливается с ошибкой:  IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to...

При этом сам сервис продолжает работать и пытается восстановить соединение. Интернет не пропадает, по крайней мере BroadcastReceiver с ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION не срабатывает. 
Соединение восстанавливается ТОЛЬКО после открытия Activity, при этом сам сервис не перезапускается.

Что это за режим такой для экономии батареи видимо? И почему соединение не восстанавливается после разблокировки экрана, а только после открытия Activity?

Comment: Проверьте, не включен ли какой-нибудь режим энергосбережения.

Comment: у всех клиентов проверять чтоли?

Comment: "у всех клиентов" можно проверять, когда вы уже понимаете причину. сейчас вы, как я понял из сообщения, не понимаете еще, почему вообще так может происходить. не?

Comment: я понимаю, что телефон переходит в режим сбережения энергии. Допускаю, что в этом режиме отключаются сетевые интерфейсы. Я не понимаю почему после включения экрана интернет восстанавливается, но сервис НЕ может подключиться к серверу до тех пор пока не запустится активность??? При том что активность была в OnPause и сервис при ее повторном запуске не перезапускается она просто переходит в OnResume.

Comment: вы говорите про какой-то определенный режим, или про "вообще"? то, что вы описываете, не похоже на doze mode. но кроме этого у пользователя есть возможность запретить фоновое обращение к сети. есть режим, когда запрещается работа любых фоновых приложений. покопайтесь в настройках телефона, может быть ответ там. как это детектить программно, сходу не могу придумать. стандартные проверки того, есть ли сеть, что в этот момент возвращают?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver с фильтром ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION вобще этот момент не отлавливает. А connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting() после перехода в этот режим все время false возврщает, как будто блокируется доступ к сети конкретно для этого сервиса. Если для фонового сервиса блокируется доступ в настройках устройства, то каким образом при одних и тех же настройках Viber продолжает работать в фоне?

Comment: версия андроида какая?

Comment: и на 6-м тестил и на 4-м

Comment: ты хочешь сказать, что одинаково воспроизводится на разных устройствах?

Comment: похоже на то...

Comment: "похоже" - это плохой ответ. сравни поведение на разных устройствах еще раз. возможно, не там ищем.

Comment: попробуй еще с WakeLock поиграть. но это уже стук в бубен начинается. нет больше идей.

Comment: с WakeLock пробовал, но как это не по фен шую -  будет постоянно аккумулятор садить в фоне. Хочется именно останавливать попытки подключения когда подключиться не возможно и восстанавливать подключение при первой возможности.

Comment: так WakeLock помогает?

Comment: если на скорую руку добавить его в сервисе то ничего не меняется.

Comment: спасибо за наводку! Таки это ограничение 6-го андроида на работу приложения в фоновом режиме. Знать бы еще как отловить включение этого ограничения? Ведь после выключения экрана еще минут 5 все работает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, это работает Doze Mode в Marshmallow.

Проверка на возможность соединиться с сервером осуществляется на устройствах с SDK 23+ дополнительным запросом к `PowerManager`. Вообще полезно так делать:

```
    if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
            connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected() &&
            (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                    || !powerManager.isDeviceIdleMode()
                    || powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()))
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Если нужен бродкаст о выходе из Doze, то можно вот так:

```
    registerReceiver(br, 
            new IntentFilter(
                    PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED));
```

Попробуйте проверить сначала, оно ли это: добавьте приложение в вайтлист из настроек (Settings -> Battery -> Battery Optimization, и там для своего приложения включить "Не экономить") и посмотрите, что изменится.

Я в свое время делал доклад, загляните в презентацию, там есть еще интересные мелочи (c 15 по 30 слайды): http://www.slideshare.net/jollydroid/android-marshmallow-13112015